# How to get a Facebook Like box using the Page Id

Tags: plugins, facebook-likebox

I am trying to create Facebook Like Box for different pages. I have only facebook page ids with me. When I type in browser like www.facebook.com/39399781765 will get me RedSox page, but when I use the same url with pageid www.facebook.com/39399781765 in Like Box, it gives an error "Could not retrieve the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in."

Can some one help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a Facebook URL for the like box you can either use the text url (https://www.facebook.com/RedSox) or the ID (39399781765).  Just don't mix and match.  It will work if you just type in `39399781765`for the Facebook Page URL it requests.